# Is the Level 9 Gem funded Land Expansion separate?

Tags: shadow-kings

When i've unlocked the Land Expansion i've always noticed a Gem costing land expansion which greys out when i get all the normal costing Land Expansions.

Now i've had a Lan Expansion unlocked at each level up when after Level 8 i noticed something, the Gem costing Land Expansion would be available at Level 9 while the next normal costing Land Expansion is unlocked at Level 10.

So i'm wondering, Is the Level 9 Gem funded Land Expansion separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Gem costing Land Expansion are just a normal Land Expansions, the difference is that by paying with Gems you can get them sooner but the required level for a normal Land Expansion  then increases.

there was a Gem costing Land Expansion at Level 18 and i had a normal Land Expansion ready to unlock at Level 32, after getting them Gems for the Level 18 Land Expansion the other one has a new level requirement of 34